# Pthread library initialization

Tags: linux, pthreads, glibc

I have created wrappers around the pthread functions using dlopen and dlsym, in order to debug and profile some issues occurring in my application.  The profiler passes all of the unit tests. Unfortunately, it appears that I have bypassed some library initialization because getenv now returns null to all input.  If I remove the profiler, the proper operation of getenv returns.

I believe that the issue is that the compiler has not linked in Libpthread because it does not see any symbols requested from the library at link time.  I have looked through the glib source but have not found an obvious run time initialization function that I can load and execute with dlsym.

I have stepped into getenv and found that __environ=null with the overrides compiled in. However, environ contains the proper values. __environ has the proper variables after removing the profiler.

Also, getenv appears to work with the pthread overrides on Ubuntu 10.04, with glibc 2.11.  Unfortunately, upgrading is not an appealing option due to existing product distribution.

Linux 2.6.31
Glib 2.5

My init code:

```
inline int init_pthreads_debugger(void)
{
    static int recursion=0;
    if(!real_pthread_create)
    {
        // we know that we are single threaded here, because we override pthread_create and
        // call this function. Therefore, recursion does not have to be guarded.
        if(recursion)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        recursion = 1;

        init_heap();

        void * handle = dlopen("libpthread.so.0",RTLD_NOW);

        real_pthread_cond_timedwait   =(real_pthread_cond_timedwait_t)dlsym(handle,"pthread_cond_timedwait");

            // more pthread initialization functions here.

        //do me last to make sure any recursion in dlsym/dlopen is caught
        real_pthread_create           =(real_pthread_create_t)dlsym(handle,"pthread_create");

        recursion = 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

//an example override
int   pthread_cond_timedwait(pthread_cond_t *c, pthread_mutex_t * m, const struct timespec * t)
{
    if(!init_pthreads_debugger()) return 0; //no thread, no sync needed.
    int ret;
    int condition_count;  
    ptd_note_unblock((void *)m,&condition_count);
    ret=real_pthread_cond_timedwait(c,m,t);
    ptd_note_block((void *)m,&condition_count);
    return ret;
}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post an example of a wrapper as well as your initialization code. I assume that by 'profiler' you mean your timing code in the wrappers?

Answer (score 1):

> I have created wrappers around the pthread functions using dlopen and dlsym

I suspect that you are attempting to build a library interposer, similar to [this one](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/lib_interposers.html).

This approach is *very* unlikely to succeed in general for pthread functions, because both `dlopen` and `dlsym` themselves call `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` (and possibly others), as does the dynamic loader itself.

Comment: Employed, I have already succeeded. The code works great in my test environment, (which did not call getenv).  When moving to the actual program that we are trying to profile, the program failed because of getenv calls, which seems very unrelated to me.

Comment: @Edward "when movind to the actual program, ... failed". That does *not* look like a success to me.

Comment: Let me rephrase myself.  __Recursion__ was never an issue as your post suggests. The initial design took that into consideration. The symptoms of the issue also do not indicate a recursion issue, which would most likely result in an ironic "stack overflow" :). Let's keep positive.

Comment: @Edward Is your code 32-bit or 64-bit? (It matters.) Also, what are *all* the functions you are trying to intercept?

Comment: test and target environments are both 32 bit. Overrides, curently: pthread_create, pthread_cond_timedwait, pthread_cond_wait, pthread_join, pthread_mutex_lock, pthread_mutex_trylock, pthread_mutex_unlock, pthread_mutex_init, pthread_mutex_destroy

Comment: @Edward Hmm, I can't seem to reproduce the problem. It might help if you can create a small stand-alone example. At a minimum, show your code for one of the interposed functions (e.g. `pthread_mutex_init`), and how you build your application (compile and link lines, whether the inteposers go into a.out or into a shared library, etc. etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I have found a workaround and a very limited program to cause the issue. I will answer the question at work tomorrow so that I can give relevant details, which the original question left out.  Unfortunately, the program is closed source and proprietary so I can not post the exact source.